# SSH command termination sequence

Tags: java, ssh

From my Java application, I connect via SSH to a server.
Every command sent, I end "\r\n". This command termination sequence works with all the command I've tried except one ("en" command) which works if only "\r" is send, but doesn't work with "\r\n". 
I can handle "en" as a special case in my code.
My question is if "\r\n" the standard way to handle line termination sequence in SSH? ie, will it work for the majority of cases?

Comment: *"My question is if "\r\n" the standard way to handle line termination sequence in SSH?"* - Yes, `CR LF` is what the SSH protocol specifies. Also see RFC 4253, [The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4253) (and friends).

Comment: The previous comment from @jww is incorrect. The specifications do not provide any clear advise or recommendation as to what command termination sequence to use when you are executing commands within a shell. If there was such a requirement it would be dealt with in the [SSH Connection Protocol] (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-6.5) and this does not deal with how a shell works, the operation of the shell is beyond the protocol specification.